# I'm Using C# MySql, while storing image path in Gridview it neglect the \ from path, due to which i'm getting error while retrieving image from path

Tags: c#, mysql, image, gridview, path

// Browse the image and save in Picturebox and path saved in label

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() {Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false})
            {
                if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filename = ofd.FileName.ToString();
                    LblFileName.Text = filename;
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename);
                }
            }
        }
```

// This convert image to Binary

```
byte[] ConvertImageToBinary(Image Img)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

// Here i'm filling data into gridview, but automatically path C:\User\Profile.jpg Becomes CuUserProfile.jpg , actually it is neglecting \ while storing path in gridview and that is why i'm getting error while retrieving image from that path, so kindly help with the solution

```
public void FillDataGridView()
        {
                    DgvEmpReg.Rows.Clear();
                    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        int n = DgvEmpReg.Rows.Add();
                        DgvEmpReg.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
                        DgvEmpReg.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
        }
```